# Error while trying to load saved object in Python using pickle

Tags: python, object, load, pickle

I have an object that I'm trying to load using pickle (Iv'e tried JSON also and still not working, it says that it is not JSON serializable) and getting the following error:

> Can't get attribute 'TextToSequence' on Code/voc-git/system/classifier_tools.py'>

Saving the object was really easy and worked perfectly, the issue rises just when I'm trying to load it.

Iv'e used the following code for the saving process:

```
with open(seq_obj_file, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(seq, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

while **seq** is the object I'm saving to the file **seq_obj_file**

For loading Iv'e used the following code:

```
with open(seq_obj, 'rb') as pkl:
        self.input_vectorizer = pickle.load(pkl)
```

While **self.input_vectorizer** is an empty variable.

The object I'm trying to save belongs to the class **TextToSequence**.

I came across the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multipile-modules), in my case I need to save the object inside a different class and can't export it to an outside main function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load files using pickle and multipile modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multipile-modules)

Comment: There's no reason not to use json here. Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: When trying to save object using json it returns an error which says that it is not JSON serializable. The solutions Iv'e found for using JSON doesn't work for my kind of object.

Comment: If you can translate the object to strings, numbers, lists, and dicts - then you can teach `json` to serialize it.
`pickle` is often a [bad idea](http://eev.ee/blog/2015/10/15/dont-use-pickle-use-camel/).

Comment: Is it? Iv'e used pickle before and never had this issue. Still I want to use pickle and will continue to try to find a solution for it.

Comment: It might fail when unpickling from a different version of Python or when the definition of the object changed since it was pickled. It's also a security risk since it can execute arbitrary code.
Not to mention that you won't be able to use your data at all from a program not written in Python.

Comment: Good point, I'll remember that.