# python3 mock doesn't work for all paths

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, patch

The Production file (production_file.py) is:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def foo(self):
        raise RuntimeError("error!")


class Caller:
    def bar(self, smth):
        obj = MyClass()
        obj.set_value(smth)

        try:
            obj.foo()
        except MyError:
            pass

        obj.set_value("str2")
        obj.foo()
```

Test file (test.py):

```
import unittest

from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import call
from production_file import MyClass, Caller

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_caller(self):
        with patch('production_file.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as MyClassMock:
            my_class_mock_obj = MyClassMock.return_value
            my_class_mock_obj.foo.side_effect = [MyError("msg"), "text"]

            caller = Caller()
            caller.bar("str1")

            calls = [call("str1"), call("str2")]

            my_class_mock_obj.set_value.assert_has_calls(calls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This above works. But if I move the production classes (MyError, MyClass, Caller) into the test file, and update patch to:

```
with patch('test.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as MyClassMock:
```

then the instance method "foo" is no longer mocked.

Does anybody have any idea why that is?

I have also experienced a similar problem with some more complex code, where the production code is in my_package/src/production_file.py while the test is in my_package/tests/test_file.py. Python yields no error for the path, the path is correct, but still the mock doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running `test.py` as `__main__` then it is not `test.MyClass` it would be `__main__.MyClass`, or in both cases `__name__+".MyClass"`.

I was able to determine that the class used and the class patched were different by adding a print statement:

```
class Caller:
    def bar(self, smth):
        print(MyClass) #lets see what we are actually making an instance of...
        obj = MyClass()
        ...
```

When the patch is applied to the class that this is using you would see something like this:

```
<MagicMock name='MyClass' spec='MyClass' id='4387629656'>
```

But when the class in moved into `test.py` you will see something like:

```
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

Which indicates:

1. There was no patching applied to `MyClass` (at least the one that is used for the test.)
2. The name of the class that needs to be patched is `__main__.MyClass`

However It is quite likely that your "more... complicated situation" is not working because of a setup like this:

```
from production_file import MyClass

class MyError(Exception):
    pass


class Caller:
    def bar(self, smth):
        print(MyClass)
        obj = MyClass()
        ...

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_caller(self):
        with patch('production_file.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as MyClassMock:
            ...
```

In this case `production_file.MyClass` is being patched and `MyClass` is being imported from `production_file` so the correct class is being patched but still the output is:

```
<class 'production_file.MyClass'>
```

This is because the Class was directly imported to the local namespace, so when the patch is applied to the `production_file` the local namespace is still unaffected, we can check that the patch was actually applied with:

```
...
def bar(self, smth):
    print(MyClass)
    from production_file import MyClass as pf_MyClass
    print(pf_MyClass)
...


#output:
<class 'production_file.MyClass'>
<MagicMock name='MyClass' spec='MyClass' id='4387847136'>
```

If this is the case you just need to import the module, not the class directly.  Then once the patch is applied you will be using it right from the file:

```
import production_file

...
class Caller:
    def bar(self, smth):
        print(production_file.MyClass)
        obj = production_file.MyClass()
        ...

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_caller(self):
        with patch('production_file.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as MyClassMock:
            ...
```

Comment: Interesting... but why does not python yield an error, if the path is wrong?

Comment: because nothing is going wrong, it is just patching the wrong place, if you have a file `test.py` and in it you ` import test` you end up with two versions of the same file loaded with different names. if you added `if __name__ == "__main__": from test import MyClass ...` etc it would work as expected since then it is patching the class you are using for the test.

Comment: I also have a problem with a more... complicated situation, where I have my_package/src/my_file.py and my_package/tests/test.py. In this case, one of my tests uses patch("src.my_file.MyClass"), but still the mock doesn't work. Is there a way for me to debug / log what the test is actually patching?

Comment: does my edit provide a more comprehensive explication / analysis?  I've never actually used unittest so I was mostly fumbling in the dark until I felt something I recognized, in this case it was inconsistent namespaces which I have seen before with [pickling classes from `__main__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multipile-modules).

Comment: Thanks! that was the fix for my problem. Interestingly enough, at print(MyClass), it yielded the full path (starting with the package name). But the problem was fixed - and the mock now got to be printed out there.

Comment: "I've never actually used unittest" - so what framework do you use? unittest is the first and only one I used for python :)

Comment: never used unittest or any equivalent framework, I've never really worked on any project large enough that it benefited from running test cases etc.