# How do I override imports of other files for unit testing

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am currently attempting to write unit tests for my Main.py's `main()` function

Here is a simplified version of my Main.py:

```
from Configuration import Configuration # Configuration.py is a file in the same dir

def main():
  try:
    Configuration('settings.ini')
  except:
    sys.exit(1) # Test path1
  sys.exit(0) # Test path2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In my `Unit Tests\MainUnitTests.py` I want to import `..\Main.py` and fake the `Configuration` class in such a way that I can hit `Test path1` and `Test path2`

I found that i can assert `sys.exit()` with the following:

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
  main()
self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

but I am having trouble overriding the `from Configuration import Configuration`

Thoughts?

So far I have tried the following within `Unit Tests\MainUnitTests.py`:

```
class FakeFactory(object):
  def __init__(self, *a):
    pass

sys.modules['Configuration'] = __import__('FakeFactory')

class Configuration(FakeFactory):
  pass
```

Another example for demonstration:

foo.py:

```
from bar import a,b

x = a()

class a(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.q = 2

y = a()

print x.q, y.q # prints '1 2' as intended

b() # I want this to print 2 without modifying bar.py
```

bar.py:

```
class a(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.q = 1

def b():
  t = a()
  print t.q
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch 
In fact it's answer to your question including examples

Comment: @farincz monkey patching doesn't seem to be working.  In the MainUnitTest.py I am importing `Configuration.py` and then creating a `class Configuration(FakeFactory)` after it ... however `Main.py's main()` is still using the Configuration class in `Configuration.py`  it seems like the two files are not sharing the same global name space

Comment: you must import Configuration and patch Configuration attribute on it
and you must do it before main is first importet! than it should work

Comment: @farincz still not working ... see `Another example for demonstration` in my question

Comment: When you use the import `from bar import a` it imports `a` directly into the namespace so monkeypatching `bar` won't help, you need to override `main.a` instead.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen could you give me an example w/ the foo.py and bar.py

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to do it with unittest before I post my answer, trying to find an old answer of mine that I think would exactly describe the issue and how to fix it (and how to do it cleanly with unittest) but I think the question may have been deleted :(

Comment: Haha [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36380658/5827215) ! Ok will write answer for your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

when you use the import

```
from bar import a
```

it import the name directly into the module, so monkeypatching `bar` won't help, you need to override `a` directly in the main file:

```
def fake_a():
    print("OVERRIDEN!")

main.a = fake_a
```

Do know that unittest has helper functions for this in [the `mock` subpackage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), I believe you could do something like:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

...
with patch("main.a", fake_a) as mock_obj: #there are additional things you can do with the mock_obj
    do_stuff()
```

This would work in your first example with `configuration` since the class that needs to be patched is not used in the global scope although `foo` uses `bar.a` as soon as it is loaded so you would need to patch it *before* even loading `foo`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

...
with patch("bar.a", fake_a) as mock_obj: #there are additional things you can do with the mock_obj
    import foo #now when it loads it will be loaded with the patched name
```

However in this case `foo.a` would not be reverted at the end of the `with` block because it can't be caught by unittest... I really hope your actual use case doesn't use the stuff to be patched at module level.