# Use class objects in other contexts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I wanted to use several thousand instances of my class in another context.

For now, I used a `pickle` file for that, but ran into severe issues when I tried to load the pickle file in another context. By this, I mean that I have somewhat resembling the following the structure:

```
main.py
   Extractors
      pickler
   Builder
      pickle_loader
```

Yet, if I try to load the pickle files with pickle_loder, it always gives a similar error to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multipile-modules).

Is there another, maybe more suitable way how I can store and reload the instances?
Since one execution of the Extractors takes around 2h, I do not want to execute them each time I experiment with the Builder.

I have also tried the solutions given, but I can't seem to get it to work with the explicit import statement.

Comment: Are `Extractors` and `Builder` classes in the same file?

Comment: no, that's what I wanted to indicate with the levels. They are in separate files, and do not even share the same subfolder. Only the main.py is located in the topmost folder

Comment: The most straightforward solution would be to add `from ... import Extractors` in the file with `Builder`. So, maybe you want to solve that explicit import statement error you mention.

Comment: which files are you running? If you are putting your files in a package structure they probably shouldn't be run as the main entry point, the key is to not pickle any objects from classes defined in the module you run.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I get the following when doing so @JaredGoguen : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Institute'`, since this is the statement I get when running from inside the main script. `Institute
Out[13]: <module 'Extractors.Institute' from ...>`

Comment: The question was more like: Is there an alternative _which does work_ and does not have these annoying limitations of pickle. In my eyes, it doesn't matter _how_ I do it...

Comment: Okay, I got something very hacky, but which seems to work.
Changing to the directory with `os.chdir` to the folder of the pickler does the trick, since then the import is simply `import Institute` instead of `import Extractors.Institute`. It's not great, probably unsafe, but it does work for now....