# Save and load scikit-learn machine learning model and function

Tags: python, serialization, scikit-learn, pickle, text-mining

I trained Naive Bayes model with scikit-learn to classify articles in my web application.To avoid learning the model repeatedly, I want to save the model and deploy it to the application later. When i search for this problem, many people recommend the `pickle` library.

I have this model :

```
import pickle
import os
def custom_tokenizer (doc) :
    tokens = vect_tokenizer(doc)
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = custom_tokenizer,stop_words = "english")
clf = MultinomialNB()
```

I have already executed `tfidf.fit_transform()` and trained `clf`. Finally, i got a model and saved `clf` classifier using this code :

```
dest = os.path.join('classifier','pkl_object')
f = open(os.path.join(dest,'classifier.pkl'),'wb')
pickle.dump(best_classifier,f,protocol = 4)
f.close()
```

I also tried to save my Vectorizer as a file this way.

```
f =  open(os.path.join(dest,'vect.pkl'),'wb')
pickle.dump(custom_tokenizer,f,protocol = 4)
pickle.dump(best_vector,f,protocol = 4)
f.close()
```

There was no error. but when i tried to load the file, this error message popped up.

```
import pickle
import os

with open(os.path.join('pkl_object','classifier.pkl'),'rb') as file :
    clf = pickle.load(file)

with open(os.path.join('pkl_vect','vect.pkl'),'rb') as file:
    vect = pickle.load(file)
```

error message :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-d4b562870a02> in <module>()
     11 
     12 with open(os.path.join('pkl_vect','vect.pkl'),'rb') as file:
---> 13     vect = pickle.load(file)
     14 
     15 '''

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'custom_tokenizer' on <module '__main__'>
```

I think the `pickle` library does not have the ability to store function properly. How can i serialize my custom `TfidfVectorizer` as a file.

Comment: Is this on the same computer? If not, verify that versions of `sklearn` are the same on both the machines.

Comment: @pault These are on the same computer.

Comment: In the file where you are loading the pickle from, have you defined custom_tokenizer? Functions need to be defined for the pickle to load properly, it needs to be in the global scope in your case, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second program also include:

```
def custom_tokenizer (doc) :
    tokens = vect_tokenizer(doc)
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
```

becuase pickle doesn't actually store information about how a class/object is constructed, as this line in your error log says `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'custom_tokenizer' on <module '__main__'>` it has no idea what is `custom_tokenizer`.Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multipile-modules) for better understanding.