# Loading pickle (python) in Google Cloud Functions fails due to namespace

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pickle

I am trying to create a GCP cloud function which loads a pickled python object for use.

The pickle is stored as a byte string.

The function fails when loading the pickle with the error: 
`"Can't get attribute 'MyClass' on <module 'google.cloud.functions.worker' from '/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py'>"`

From that I am assuming the issue is due to namespace, as when the object is created it is stored in `<module '__main__'>`

I found [Unable to load files using pickle and multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multiple-modules#_=_) which is useful but I don't think either of the solutions would be possible to implement in cloud functions.

How would I go about loading a pickled object which was pickled outside of the function?

N.B I do have the MyClass class in the function.

Comment: Please add the code snippet to see how you're calling the function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is google cloud functions is actually importing and calling your code from its own `__main__`. so while you have Myclass in your `main.py` it will show up as `main.Myclass` when you pickled file is expecting `__main__.Myclass`. I was able to hack it by simply adding the class directly to the `__main__` module by doing `setattr(sys.modules["__main__"],'MyClass',MyClass)` before you load your pickled file.