# Attribute Error : pickle.load() Seldon Deployment

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, seldon

I am doing a seldon deployment. I have created custom pipelines using sklearn and it is in the directory **MyPipelines/CustomPipelines.py**. The main code ie. **my_prediction.py** is the file which seldon will execute by default (based on my configuration). In this file I am importing the custom pipelines. If I execute my_prediction.py in my local (PyCharm) it executes fine. But If I deploy it using Seldon I get the error : `Attribute Error: Can't get Attribute 'MyEncoder'`

It is unable to load modules in CustomPipelines.py. I tried all the solutions from [Unable to load files using pickle and multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multiple-modules) None of them worked.

**MyPipelines/CustomPipelines.py**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class MyEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        df = X
        vars_cat = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].dtypes == 'O']
        cat_with_na = [var for var in vars_cat if df[var].isnull().sum() > 0]
        df[cat_with_na] = df[cat_with_na].fillna('Missing')

        return df
```

**my_prediction.py**

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import dill
from MyPipelines.CustomPipelines import MyEncoder
from MyPipelines.CustomPipelines import *
import MyPipelines.CustomPipelines

class my_prediction:
   
    def __init__(self):

        file_name = 'model.sav'
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as model_file:
                self.model = pickle.load(model_file)

    def predict(self, request):
        data = request.get('ndarray')
        columns = request.get('names')
        X = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
        predictions = self.model.predict(X)
        return predictions
```

Error:

```
File microservice/my_prediction.py in __init__                       
self.model = pickle.load(model_file)                 
Attribute Error: Can't get Attribute 'MyEncoder' on <module '__main__' from 'opt/conda/bin/seldon-core-microservice'
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the constrains of the `pickle` module is that it expects that the same classes (under the same module) are available in the environment where the artifact gets *unpickled*. In this case, it seems like your `my_prediction` class is trying to unpickle a `MyEncoder` artifact, but that class is not available on that environment.

As a quick workaround, you could try to make your `MyEncoder` class available on the environment where `my_prediction` runs on (i.e. having the same folders / files present there as well). Otherwise, you could look at alternatives to `pickle`, like `cloudpickle` or `dill`, which can serialise your custom code as well (although these also come with their own set of caveats).