# why unpickling functions is not possible using pickle?

Tags: python, function, pickle

when i use pickle package to serialize a dict object for example, i can load it in another context without problem. but it's not the case for functions unless i import it again as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732354/unable-to-load-files-using-pickle-and-multiple-modules#:%7E:text=111,class_def.py%20module%3A) (i don't know if it's feasible in case of functions defined inside notebooks).  But why this behaviour?, how function object is different from dict object?

example:

open notebook **A**, run the following:

```
def func(x):
   return x**2
with open("myfile", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(func,f)
```

open notebook **B**, run the following:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    func = pickle.load(f)
```

this would return

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'func' on <module '__main__'>
```

Comment: Indeed, [that is the documented behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), although I'm confident that what the OP wants _can_ be done, I just don't know how.

Comment: Unpickling functions is not possible using pickle because pickle is designed to store data in a serialized format, and functions are not serializable.

Comment: @rodrigo, you're right, i'v read the same thing about the save method of pytorch models

Comment: @jasonharper, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: Actually try this. `func = pickle.load(f, "rb"))`

Comment: @Kylar, i think i should read more about serialization